# Why does my code keep return an infinite number of Current Balance: 0?

Tags: java

I know I'm missing something really important here. Something tells me the code is redundant. When I execute the below code,

```
package sct;

public class Account {

private static int balance;
public Account(String Account, double d) {
    System.out.println("Intial state");
    return;
}
public static Object displayBalance(int balance){
    System.out.println("Current Balance: " + balance);
    return displayBalance(balance);}
static Account usAccount = new Account("US account", 100.00);
static Account chAccount = new Account("Swiss account", 1000000.00);    

public static int amountWithdrawing(int balance, int withdrawAmount)
    {   System.out.println("Withdraw Amount: " + withdrawAmount);
return amountWithdrawing(balance, withdrawAmount);
}   
public static int amountDepositing(int balance, int depositAmount) {
System.out.println("Depositing Amount: " + depositAmount);
return balance = balance + depositAmount;
}
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount " + 20);
    System.out.println("Deposit Amount " + 200);
    System.out.println("Ending balances");
    displayBalance(balance);
    balance = amountWithdrawing(100, 20);
    displayBalance(balance);
    balance = amountDepositing(1000000, 200);
    System.out.println("usAccount Current Balance: " + usAccount);
    System.out.println("chAccount Current Balance: " + chAccount);}
 }
```

I keep getting the below in console:

```
Current Balance: 0
infinite loop

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.lang.System$2.encodeASCII(System.java:2489)
at           java.base/sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(SingleByte.java:220)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(SingleByte.java:276)
at     java.base/java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:585)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:374)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:361)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.lockedWrite(StreamEncoder.java:162)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:143)
at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.implFlushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:178)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:163)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.implWriteln(PrintStream.java:848)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.writeln(PrintStream.java:826)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:1168)
at sct.Account.displayBalance(Account.java:11)
at sct.Account.displayBalance(Account.java:12)
infinite loop
```

I'm an epic noob. this is my third time writing code so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
public static Object displayBalance(int balance){
    System.out.println("Current Balance: " + balance);
    return displayBalance(balance);}
```

You are declaring a function "displayBalance". In this function, you print out the current balance that was put into the function, then return...by calling displayBalance again, which prints again, then calls displayBalance again, which prints again, then...

See the problem?

If you want this function to print and then exit, simply change the "public static Object" line to "public static void", and replace "return displayBalance(balance);" at the end with "return;".

You should fix your other functions with the same method, because they will also loop (recurse) infinitely. Google "recursion" to learn more about how this type of infinite loop works, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I was able to get the infinite loop to stop! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to *Java*, I recommend reading the *[The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)*, by *Oracle*, the company which currently own *Java*.

The main issue I'm seeing is that you're using the *return* keyword, when it's not needed.

You only need to use *return* when the method should return a result.
For example, you're assigning a value to a variable.

```java
int value = example();
```

Your method *displayBalance* simply prints the data to the standard-out.  Thus, a return is not necessary.

Methods that do not return any value can use the *void* keyword.

```java
public static void displayBalance(int balance) {
    System.out.println("Current Balance: " + balance);
}
```

If you *did* want to return a value, there is no need to use the *method* name, within the return.
Simply return the value.

```java
public static int amountWithdrawing(int balance, int withdrawAmount) {
    System.out.println("Withdraw Amount: " + withdrawAmount);
    return balance - withdrawAmount;
}
```

The following tutorial outlines method declaration and use.
*[Defining Methods (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*.

Finally, you're using a *println* call that uses the *usAccount* object.
This will simply print out the object name and its *[hash-code](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())* value—not the *balance*.

If you'd like to have it print a specific value, you can implement the *[toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString())* method.

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(balance);
}
```

Here is the complete code, after making these adjustments.

```java
public class Account {
    private static int balance;

    public Account(String Account, double d) {
        System.out.println("Intial state");
    }

    public static void displayBalance(int balance) {
        System.out.println("Current Balance: " + balance);
    }

    static Account usAccount = new Account("US account", 100.00);
    static Account chAccount = new Account("Swiss account", 1000000.00);

    public static int amountWithdrawing(int balance, int withdrawAmount) {
        System.out.println("Withdraw Amount: " + withdrawAmount);
        return balance - withdrawAmount;
    }

    public static int amountDepositing(int balance, int depositAmount) {
        System.out.println("Depositing Amount: " + depositAmount);
        return balance = balance + depositAmount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount " + 20);
        System.out.println("Deposit Amount " + 200);
        System.out.println("Ending balances");
        displayBalance(balance);
        balance = amountWithdrawing(100, 20);
        displayBalance(balance);
        balance = amountDepositing(1000000, 200);
        System.out.println("usAccount Current Balance: " + usAccount);
        System.out.println("chAccount Current Balance: " + chAccount);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(balance);
    }
}
```